# Android: Text View horizontal scroll does not work for short length text

Tags: textview, android

The text scrolls only if it is long length (lot of text). 
For example: 
This scrolls: "Hello World, How are you doing today this fine day folks?" 
This does not scroll: "How are you?"

```
 <TextView
                android:id="@+id/my_name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textStyle="bold"

                android:singleLine="true"                
                android:ellipsize="marquee" 
                android:marqueeRepeatLimit ="marquee_forever"
                android:scrollHorizontally="true"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true" >
            </TextView>
```

The text itself is set programatically: textView.setText("whatever");
How can i make the text always scroll irrespective of length?

Comment: I think the scroll view is working only when the view going outside the limit.